# Accidentally pinned My Documents folder to HDD

Tags: windows, file-location, my-documents

So I was following these instructions here (https://www.pcworld.com/article/2025058/answer-line-move-data-files-from-an-ssd-to-a-hard-drive.html) to move the My Documents folder to the new HDD I'd just formatted (D:). When choosing "move" to a new location, I didn't choose a folder on D, I just chose D. Normally when you write click "My Documents" > Properties, you get My Documents Properties. Now when I right click "My Documents" > Properties, it shows me the properties for the Hard Drive itself. I can't seem to find the original My Documents. Any advice?

Comment: can this be useful? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/310746/configuration-of-the-my-documents-folder

Comment: Thank you Giovanni, that solved it for me:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, Name: Personal; Changing the value to a path that isn't the root of the drive fixed it.

Comment: Please write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Giovanni, that solved it for me:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders, Name: Personal;
```

Changing the value to a path that isn't the root of the drive fixed it.